# Ionic native splash screen vs capacitor splash screen?

Tags: ionic-framework, splash-screen, capacitor, ionic5

I want to build an Angular + Ionic5 + capacitor app, and I found there are lots of splash screen approaches.

1. Ionic native splash screen.
2. Capacitor splash screen.
3. Cordova plugin splash screen （Which I think will not be considered because I will use capacitor instead of Cordova. correct me if I am wrong.）

Which one should I use, is there any big difference between them?

Comment: Capacitor Splashscreen. Since you're using Capacitor.

Comment: @johnborges Thanks for your response. BTW, should I use capacitor, since I just start building an ionic app

Comment: I would recommend it. Especially since Ionic is defaulting to it now.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic Native Splash Screen and Cordova Plugin Splash Screen are the same thing and they don't work with Capacitor, it's listed on the [known incompatible plugins section](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cordova/known-incompatible-plugins).

If you check [Ionic Native docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/splash-screen), it tells you to install `cordova-plugin-splashscreen`, Ionic Native plugins are just wrappers around Cordova plugins so they are easier to use in projects that use typescript instead of javascript.